# Windows Phone 8.1 xaml - read language resources from external project

Tags: xaml, resources, windows-phone-8.1

I have portable library in which I have AppLocalizations.resw resource files. I can read it in the code behind (which is obsolete, but working):

```
new Windows.ApplicationModel.Resources.ResourceLoader("Assembly/AppLocalizations")
```

But how can I use it from the xaml? When I try to read it this way, the text is blank, even if the key in the resource file is *Key.Text*

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="Key" />
```

I was triying to import it in the App.xaml, but with no success.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code with Windows Phone Universal Apps, but with a general resources:

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_BlackStyle}" x:Uid="/Resources/txtIPName" Name="txtIPName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="33,149,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="IP:" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

Then if u had exertanl library, I think the code is:

```
<TextBlock x:Uid="/Assembly/AppLocalizations/Key" />
```

Tell me if I solve your problem! Good luck man! :)

Comment: That's a really stupid syntax! But makes sense. It works, thanks.

Comment: Hahahaha man you work with windows! Welcome to the jungle! You're welcome. :D